# Which salt is a surfactant and lowers the surface tension of the water?

Tags: water, surfactants, salt

I am doing my experiment on the surface tension of the water. How to show the decrease of surface tension of water with the increase in the concentration of salt? Is there any salt that lowers the surface tension of the water?

Comment: Related (though it doesn't quite answer your question): https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/49570/does-nacl-reduce-the-surface-tension-of-water/49584#49584

Comment: This one answers your question: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/134948/effect-of-solutes-on-surface-tension/134970#134970. Technically, I guess Sodium Lauryl Sulphate would count as a salt (it's a cation-anion pair).

Comment: Soap is a salt as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Effect of solutes on surface tension](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/134948/effect-of-solutes-on-surface-tension)

Answer (score 1):

[Cetyltrimethylammonium bromide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cetrimonium_bromide) (CTAB) and its cheaper [chloro homologue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cetrimonium_chloride) are just two examples of cationic detergents commercially available and frequently used e.g., for hair shampoos.  They are called *cationic* because beside lipophilic alkyl groups their head group is positively charged:

[image]

([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cetrimonium_bromide))

Note, there equally are *anionic* and *nonionc* detergents, too.

There are multiple approaches to demonstrate their effect to lower the surface tension of water.  Just a qualitative illustration is placing carefully a paper clip on water which will sink after the addition of a detergent:

[image]

([source](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_tension))

If you are up to quantify the effect, the measurement of the [contact angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_angle) between the liquid and the solid is a frequently used approach.  Again, the *Journal of Chemical Education* ([2017JChemEduc230](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jchemed.6b00546)) published a lab class showcasing the relevance of surface tension e.g., when spraying leaves of lettuce.  A second nice demonstration I recall from this journal was to record the rising meniscus in pasteur pipettes ([2016JChemEduc1647](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jchemed.6b00128)) in variation of the concentration of [sodium dodecyl sulfate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_dodecyl_sulfate) (a popular anionic surfactant).